# PHP Month Locale with mktime

Tags: php, date, locale, mktime

So, im triying to do this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");
$MonthName = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
```

But the MonthName still is in english.

I tried this too:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");
$monthObject   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
$MonthName = $monthObject-> format('F');
```

Locale didnt work either. Display name is in english.

Comment: so you want to input `nov` and get `Noviembre` out?

Comment: Now it displays November, i want to display Noviembre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `strftime()` since `date()` and `DateTime::format` are not locale aware:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");    
$month = 11;
$MonthName = strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
echo $MonthName; //noviembre
```

Comment: @Uxio90 Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: I believe Windows uses different locale strings as [mentioned here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-notes).

Comment: Thanks. It was that, I usually code in Debian, and didnt know Windows had different locale strings.

Appreciate man.